# Minimize $f(r,X)$ over all sets $X$ using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

If a set of numbers $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ $($such that each $a_i \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\})$ and an $r \in \mathbb{N}$ are given, find set $X = \{x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_r \ | \ x_0 = 0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_r = n\}$ such that $f(r,X) := \displaystyle\max_{j=0}^{r-1} \sum_{i = x_j}^{x_{j+1}-1} a_i$ is minimized over all possible $X$.

---

I can think of a brute force approach, that is, generate $\Theta ({{n-1} \choose {r-1}})$ sets $X$ and calculate the $\max$ for each $X$, each of which takes as many as $r$ steps. This is a very inefficient approach. How do I make it better? I feel like there is a way using DP. (Please feel free to edit the title if this is not DP).

This seems like a possible solution. What if we pre-compute $\displaystyle\Sigma_{i=j}^{j+k} {a_i}$ $(k \geq 0)$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$ first and then create a DP with function $$\text{best}(p,q) = \text{best way of having } q \text{ intervals such that we end at } [p-x,p] \text{ for some } x \geq 0$$ Our goal is to find $\text{best}(n,r)$ and backtrack to find the intervals.

$\text{best}(p,q) = \min \{ \text{best}(p,q-1), \ \max(\text{best}(p-1,q-1), \text{dist}(p-1,p)), \ \max(\text{best}(p-2,q-1), \text{dist}(p-2,p)), \dots) \}$

where $\text{dist}(x,y)$ = $\displaystyle\Sigma_{i=x}^{y} a_i$ which is pre-computed. This probably works but the backtracking seems difficult and time-hungry.

I tried greedy and I could generate counter-examples right away. Was not very helpful.

Comment: Hint: First prove that there is always an optimal solution with a very simple structure.

Comment: (A way to do this is to consider an arbitrary solution that does not have this structure, and show that by moving it "towards" this structure, you never make the solution worse. It follows that repeated steps will eventually get you to a solution with the structure, and it will be no worse than what you started with.)

Comment: I understand that that is the approach. Still, I fail to see how the proceed. Can you give me a possible construction?

Comment: What simple structure did you decide on?

Comment: How about pre-computing the $\Sigma_{i=j}^{j+k} {a_i}$ $(k \geq 0)$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$ first and then create a DP with function best(p,q) = best way of having $q$ intervals such that we end at $[p-x,p]$ for some $x \geq 0$. Our goal is to find best(n,r) and backtrack to find the intervals. best(p,q) = min(best(p,q-1), max(best(p-1,q-1),dist(p-1,p)), max(best(p-2,q-1), dist(p-2,p)), $\cdots$)) where dist(x,y) = $\Sigma_{i=x}^{y} a_i$ which is pre-computed. This probably works but the backtracking seems difficult.

Comment: The idea I'm thinking of expoits the fact that no numbers are negative: A sum of $n$ nonnegative numbers is always $\ge$ the sum of a subset of any $n-1$ of them. This suggests that you should be looking for solutions with _____ intervals. One simple way of making an interval _____er does not lead to a solution that is guaranteed to be no worse -- but can you come up with a refinement that does give such a guarantee?

Comment: To clarify, by "there is always an optimal solution with a very simple structure", I don't mean that there is a simple algorithm, I mean that we can afford to restrict ourselves to a small part of the space all possible solutions to the problem (because we can prove that this small part of the solution space will always contain an optimal solution). This will ultimately lead to a simple algorithm -- but the first step is to think of a way to restrict the solution space, and prove (or at least convince yourself) that it will work.

Comment: @j_random_hacker We denote by $[a_r,a_s]$ the sum $a_r + \dots + a_s$. Do you mean we break it into intervals such that the $[a_r, a_s] \geq \frac{a_1 + \dots a_n}{n}$? That is, choose the least number $x_1$ such that $[a_0, a_{x_1}] \geq \frac{a_1 + \dots a_n}{n}$ and repeat this for all other ${x_j}'s$. This is essentially greedy and not DP in that case.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind. There is always an optimal solution in which every interval is of length 1. Once you have proved this is the case -- e.g., by showing that any optimal solution can be transformed into a solution with $\le$ cost in which every interval has length 1 -- you can apply a simple algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: @j_random_hacker In fact, my greedy doesn't work. I had a slight feeling that this would fail, and it really does. This leaves DP as one of the only probable techniques to solve it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It was just this, that you spent a lot of time, none of that really helped me. AT ALL. This is my final try before I delete the question and post it on Reddit. And updating it didn't really bring it to the 'Active' section either.

Comment: My last comment explains how to find an optimal solution, but you seem to have ignored it.

Comment: My apologies, I see now that I missed the constraints on $x_0$ and $x_r$ -- without these, the problem would be much simpler. shgr1092's greedy-within-binary-search is the way to go.

Comment: @j_random_hacker No worries, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main idea: Instead of finding $X$ itself, find the minimum value for $f(r,X)$. After you do this, it is easy to find a minimal $X$. Simply greedily add elements to an interval until the sum of the interval is too large - once this happens, create a new interval at that position.

Finding the minimal value for $f(r,X)$ is a classic (maybe prototypical) binary search problem. The algorithm is as follows: binary search over the answer. Within your binary search, greedily add elements to an interval until the sum of the interval is higher than the answer - once this happens, create a new interval. (Note that this is the same method as is used to construct $X$.) At the end, check how many intervals you have formed - if it is $\leq r$ then it is possible to divide the array into $r$ intervals such that $f(r,X) \leq ans$. The time complexity is $O(NlogS)$, where $S$ is the sum of all $a_i$.

Although binary search does work for all practical values, your statement does state $\mathbb{N}$ as the possible size of elements. If elements can be arbitrarily large, we can use DP as you mentioned, fairly similar to the DP that you use. $best(p,q)$ can be the minimum $f(\cdot)$ taking $q$ intervals from the first $p$ elements. By transitioning in the same way as your statement, we get a trivial $O(N^3)$ solution.

We can also optimise this DP. One optimisation: $best(x,q)$ is monotonically increasing as $x$ increases, but $dist(x,p)$ is monotonically decreasing. So, we can use binary search to find the intersection of the two lines. The transition is now $O(logN)$ and the overall complexity is $O(N^2logN)$.

Important thing to note: this DP avoids the issues with your DP because it doesn't store the actual $X$ within the DP itself.

Comment: Binary search $\text{ans}$ over the interval $\left[\frac{\sum a_i}{n}, \sum a_i \right]$. And when we have $\leq r$ intervals while greedy searching, then it is NOT necessarily possible to divide it into $r$ intervals such that $f(r,X) \leq \text{ ans}$. Take $r=3, S = \{2,3,1,5,7\}$. When $\text{ans}=8$, we have $(2+3+1+5,7+6)$ form the initial intervals. Then we need to break it such that 7,6 gets separated. It isn't possible to break into intervals such that each sum is $\leq \text{ ans}$.

Comment: As for the "breaking", we can use break[x][y] that returns the proper break in O(1) or we can use something similar to Kadane's algorithm to compute the break in O(N). But pre computing this saves time.

Comment: @oldsailorpopoye Greedy must work (why? because each interval in the greedy has sum $\leq ans$, since we create a new interval if the sum would become greater than $ans$). For your example, we would get $(2,3,1)$,$(5)$,$(7)$,$(6)$. Since we have 4 intervals, we can't divide into 3 intervals, so $f(r,X) > 8$.

Comment: @oldsailorpopoye At the end, greedy will produce a division into $\leq r$ intervals s.t. each interval has sum $\leq f(r,X)$ where $f(r,X)$ is the answer found from binary search. We can transform this into a solution with exactly $r$ intervals by splitting some of the intervals up (can be done arbitrarily).

Comment: I misunderstood your solution in that case. I was treating $\text{ans}$ as the upper bound instead of answer and the resulting ans will be the min of all these ans for which we get a proper partitioning into $r$ intervals. Yours is a neater approach now that I realize it.

Comment: Just to clarify, my DP doesn't store the X positions/values either. best returns the $\text{ans}$ basically. Also, what exactly is the intersection when the best elements are (15 20 25 30 35) and the dist elements are (33 32 31 30 29)? I don't get this intersection thing.

Comment: @oldsailorpopoye In your example it is 30 (at that position best and dist are equal). If it was, say, best = (15 20 25 30 35), dist = (33 32 31 29 28), then it is either max(30,29) or max(25,31) [check the first position where best>dist and last where best<dist]. Obviously the min of these two is 30 so the answer would be 30.
If you consider best and dist as graphs on a coordinate plane it is obvious why this works.